# Preprocessing of target data set in Transfer learning approach

Tags: neural-networks, normalization, standardization, data-preprocessing, transfer-learning

So the idea of transfer learning approach is to pre-train a model on source data set and then re-train (or fine-tune) the model on the target data set. But what about preprocessing? If I choose to have the data normalized to mean 0 and std 1, I will first compute mean and std from source data set and train the model. Should the target data (from different domain) be normalized using mean and std computed from source data set or from target data set? And what about new unseen data used for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If available, you should preprocess/standardise your target data using the source. Because, they can be of different characteristics before the preprocessing. The unseen test data will also use the source statistics. For example, in this ResNet [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.01187.pdf), they share the mean/std used in their preprocessing step. Also, the PyTorch library contains [precomputed](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/97304e232807082c2e7b54c597615dc0ad8f6173/imagenet/main.py#L197) mean/std in their code belonging to ImageNet dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you maybe have any idea for some source (some paper or book) for this claim?

Comment: Apologies that my previous answer was too much focused on unavailability of these metrics.

Comment: Hm, that changed the answer... My idea is to train an autoencoder for anomaly detection using TL approach, do you think it is a good idea to preprocess target data using metrics computed on source data?

Comment: If available, yes, because o/w your training will take longer (weights will try to adapt to your data's mean/std)